# How to make UI Automator wait until TextView's text value changes

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am currently doing some cross-app functional UI testing.

There is a TextView that exists and that I must test for its text value. I must thus find a way to wait for the TextView's text value to change.

Here is my usecase :

```java
final UiSelector contextualInformation = new UiSelector().resourceId(resourceId);
final UiObject contextualInformationUiObject = mDevice.findObject(contextualInformation);

// I would like to find something to fulfill this statement
Boolean conditionWasMet = contextualInformationUiObject.wait(Until./*a search condition for text to contain given substring*/, timeout);

assertThat(conditionWasMet, is(notNullValue()));
assertThat(conditionWasMet, is(true));
assertThat(contextualInformationUiObject.exists(), is(true));
assertThat(contextualInformationUiObject.getText(), containsString(/*given substring*/));
```

I am well aware of the existence of `Until.textContains(/*substring*/)` but I do not know how to apply it to/with `contextualInformation` or `contextualInformationUiObject` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if your process doesn't possess any `onFinished` callback, there is no way but to use `Thread.sleep()`. This is what I did on my latest project:

```
final long waitingTime = 5000L;
Thread.sleep(averageWaitingTime);
```

You can just adjust the `waitingTime`. The idea is to buy enough time for your process to finish.

Comment: I settled for this solution, even though it is not exactly what I expected but there seems to be no better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to wait a text using `UiObject`, only `UiObject2`. To wait for a text, you can use:

```
fun waitElement(expectedText: String): UiObject2 {
    val view = device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text(expectedText)), TIMEOUT)

    if (view == null) {
        throw Exception(
                "After waiting for ${TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TIMEOUT)} seconds, " +
                "the text $expectedText was not found"
        )
    }
    else {
        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use UiObject2 instead

```
    val button = device.findObject(By.text("Click on me"))
    val textView = device.findObject(By.res("CounterTextView"))
    assertTrue(textView.wait(Until.textContains("Counter is: 0"), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT))
    button.click()
    assertTrue(textViewtextView.wait(Until.textContains("Counter is: 1"), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT))
```